# Making footnotes fit the border of the table using longtable package

Tags: tables, footnotes, longtable

**Problem:**

Making footnotes fit the width of the table using the `longtable` package.

**Question:**

- In what way can the footnotes in the MWE be modified to fit the width of the table?

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,longtable,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}

\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccccccccccc}
\caption{Table caption here}\label{chap1:tab1}
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{13}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{13}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot

\toprule
 &  \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{Criteria}} \\
\midrule
   \textbf{Solutions} & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J & K & L \\
\midrule
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccc}

    \fontsize{8}{11}\selectfont \textbf{A:} Text text text & 
    \fontsize{8}{11}\selectfont \textbf{F:} Text text text text text & 
    \fontsize{8}{11}\selectfont \textbf{J:} Text text text text text \\

    \fontsize{8}{11}\selectfont \textbf{B:} Text text text text text & 
    \fontsize{8}{11}\selectfont \textbf{G:} Text text text text text text & 
    \fontsize{8}{11}\selectfont \textbf{K:} Text text text text textText text text text \\

    \fontsize{8}{11}\selectfont \textbf{C:} Text text text text text & 
    \fontsize{8}{11}\selectfont \textbf{H:} Text text & 
    \fontsize{8}{11}\selectfont \textbf{L:} Text text text text textText text text text \\

    \fontsize{8}{11}\selectfont \textbf{D:} Text text text text text & 
    \fontsize{8}{11}\selectfont \textbf{I:} Text text text \\

    \fontsize{8}{11}\selectfont \textbf{E:} Text text text text text

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear as your example doesn't have any `\footnote`, it has some text in a smaller font, but that's not really the same thing. longtable supports normal per-page footnotes, if you want the footnotes to be aligned with the table perhaps you really want table notes with the footnote texts coming at the end of the table (rather than on each page?)

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for to align the notes with the table width. What is the appropriate way forward to achieve this?

Comment: just use a single longtable not two, then alignment is automatic, you can use `\multicolumn{...}` so your notes span across as many columns as necessary

Comment: Been experimenting one hour without any success. May I ask for some additional guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `\extracolumnsep{\fill}` so the problem of determining the table borders is made trivially simple: the table is known in advance to be `\textwidth` wide. So all you need to do is lay out your notes in three columns taking up the full width.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,longtable,booktabs,multicol}

\begin{document}

\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}

\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}


\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccccccccccc@{}}
\caption{Table caption here}\label{chap1:tab1}
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{13}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{13}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot

\toprule
 &  \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{Criteria}} \\
\midrule
   \textbf{Solutions} & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J & K & L \\
\midrule
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{longtable}

\begin{multicols}{3}\footnotesize\everypar{\hangindent=20pt}\parindent=0pt

   \textbf{A:} Text text text 

   \textbf{B:} Text text text text text 

   \textbf{C:} Text text text text text 

   \textbf{D:} Text text text text text 

   \textbf{E:} Text text text text text

   \textbf{F:} Text text text text text 

   \textbf{G:} Text text text text text text 

   \textbf{H:} Text text 

   \textbf{I:} Text text text 

   \textbf{J:} Text text text text text 


   \textbf{K:} Text text text text textText text text text 


   \textbf{L:} Text text text text textText text text text 

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, to be quite honest I wouldn't have been able to solve that on my own. But this has been a good learning opportunity for future tables. One last question, how would I decrease/increase the space between the columns?

Comment: You have specified the inter-column column space should be expanded arbitrarily to force the table full width, that's what `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` means. If you don't do that, the inter-column space won't be expanded, but then my answer doesn't apply as you need to work out how wide the table is before setting the notes:-)

Comment: I understand, I was wondering if there was a way of modifying the width of the multicols without touching the width of the table.

Comment: @kexxcream oh the multicols columns, I thought you meant the table columns, just `\setlength\columnsep{...}` to whatever you want before starting `multicols`

Comment: Thanks for saving my evening, it's people like you that makes me motivated to stay in academia. :-)

Comment: @kexxcream despite the fact that I left:-)

Comment: But luckily your willingness to guide people hasn't.